# How to add noise to a specific part using shader editor

Tags: texturing

I made this using *Voronoi Texture* node with *Color Ramp* connecting it to *Color* and *Bump*. I would like to add noise only to the flat areas. Any method?
[image]

Comment: I guess in the flat areas the color output of the color ramp is black. So what you could do is use a _Math_ node set to _Greater Than_ with _Threshold_ 0 and use this as mix factor for a _Mix RGB_ node. In _Color1_ plug the _Noise Texture_, in _Color2_ the color ramp output you use for the bump. Maybe you have to multiply the _Noise Texture_ with a very small value or use a _Map Range_ node, since otherwise the noise bumps will be as high as the voronoi bumps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this node tree:

[image]

by changing the "greater than" you can choose the right factor.

I just mixed the color of the noise here - you can of course do whatever you want with it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris

Answer (score 4):

What you could do is use a *Math* node set to *Greater Than* with *Threshold* 0 and use this as mix factor for a *Mix RGB* node. In *Color1* plug the *Noise Texture*, in *Color2* the color ramp output you use for the bump. Maybe you have to multiply the *Noise Texture* with a very small value or use a *Map Range* node, since otherwise the noise bumps will be as high as the voronoi bumps. (This might not be too bad with *Bump*, but for better visual display I used *Displacement* as well and there it might be problematic.)

[image: noise]

Comment: Thank You Gordon

Comment: @ArunNura If Chris' or my answer helped you, you might consider accepting one of them: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)